# ASP.NET UpdatePanel and JavaScript functions

Tags: .net, ajax, updatepanel

I would like to call JavaScript functions to show/hide a loading animation when a DropDownList is changed in an UpdatePanel.

Here is the DopDownList in an UpdatePanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_size" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_size_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">/asp:DropDownList>
    ...
```

Here are the JavaScript functions I want to call

```
function ShowLoadingAnimation() { ... }
function HideLoadingAnimation() { ... }
```

Do I use triggers? How do I use it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PageRequestManager`'s `beginRequest` and `endRequest` handlers to show/hide animation. The implementation details are on [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager beginRequest Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397432.aspx) and [Walkthrough: Animating ASP.NET UpdatePanel Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398866.aspx) MSDN pages.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the JavaScript tag in your aspx page:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestHandler); 
function endRequestHandler() { yourJsFunction }
```